# Identification of a limit point of a sequence of solution of ODE

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $v^0$ and $v^1$ be the following vector fields over $\big(\mathbb{R}_+^*\big)^3$: for $x\in\big(\mathbb{R}_+^*\big)^3$ and $1\leq i\leq 3$,

\begin{align*}
& v^0_i(x)=x_i(x_{i-1}-x_{i+1}) \\
& v^1_i(x)=x_{i-1}-x_i.
\end{align*}

The flows of $v^0$ and $v^1$ preserve $H(x)=x_1+x_2+x_3$ ($H$ can actually be seen as a Hamiltonian for $v^0$). Also the flow of $v^0$ preserves $z(x)=x_1x_2x_3$, and for the flow of $v^1$, $z(x)$ is increasing (in particular, all $x_i$ remain positive under these two flows). Hence, for $N\geq 1$, under the flow of $(Nv^0+v^1)$, $H$ remains constant and $z$ is increasing.

Let $x_N$ be defined for $t\in [0,1]$ as the solution of the ODE $\dot{x}_N=(Nv^0+v^1)(x_N)$, satisfying $x_N(t=0)=(1,0,0)$. The sequence of functions $(x_N)$ is not uniformly equicontinuous and is not relatively compact. However, the sequence $y_N=z(x_N)$ is uniformly equicontinuous and hence admits an accumulation point $y$, defined for $t\in[0,1]$.

**Question:** is it possible to prove that $y$ is increasing?

I already proved that y is solution of $\dot{y}=v(y)$ where $v$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function over $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, but is not differentiable at $0$. Hence the solution of the previous ODE is not unique and $y$ is not fully identified.